# Converting Excel to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, xlsx

This is my first attempt at something like this, How do I get the desired output?

[image: cluster sheet]

the desired `json` is like so

```
{
    "cluster": "ABC,DEF,GHI,SMU,RTR,DIP-OLM"
}
```

I am following various answers here, and I only have this

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'my_template.xlsx'
ans = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='clusters')
f = ans.to_json(indent=2)
print(f)
```

which gives

```
{
  "service_name":{
    "0":"ABC",
    "1":"DEF",
    "2":"GHI",
    "3":"SMU",
    "4":"MDS",
    "5":"APS_OLM",
    "6":"RTR",
    "7":"DIP-OLM",
    "8":"LMS-JSX"
  }
}
```

Some help would open the way for me to get a better understanding of this. Thanks in advance. Would `xlrd` be better suited for this? There are a couple of more sheets that have to be nested inside of this `json`.

**INFO** :- The complete `json` is something like this:

```
{
    "cluster": "ABC,DEF,GHI,SMU,RTR,DIP-OLM",
    "version": "07.04.00",
    "ABC": {
        "microservices": "ABC - HA (07.04.00)",
        "maps": {
            "pam_bld_nr": "21",
            "pam_bld_nr_frontend": "21",
            "pam_bld_nr_backend": "21",
            "pam_bt_dk_size": "200"
        },
        
        "new_block": {
            "additional_param": "additional_param_value",
            "additional_param": "additional_param_value2"
        }
    },
```

Rest of the values need to come from the other 2 sheets in the same file. Just FYI.

Comment: Do you really want your output to be one concatenated string of all rows? (`"cluster": "ABC,DEF,GHI,SMU,RTR,DIP-OLM"` ). Your script now turns the different rows of the Excel-file into different items of a json dict. Which would seem more useful (but off course that depends on what you want to do with it)

Comment: Yes. That is the requirement. That is why I have the feeling I need to use `xlrd` . This is one of 3 sheets in the file. The other two are to be nested inside the same `json`.

Comment: close the question?? At least leave a comment

Comment: @AbhishekRai I think the right way would be to read all existing excel files by your current approach (using pd.read_excel()) and then if output doesn't look the way you want then do extra transformations using regular Python code. I don't think `xlrd` will output for you exactly JSON that you want. Anyway you'll have to do extra transformations afterwards in both cases of `pandas` and `xlrd`.

Comment: @Arty Oh! So, after getting the `json` from `pandas` make the desired changes to the output `json` using regular python code ? ..